# How to record intellij execution into Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a need where executed API tests from Intellij(rest assured framework), to record into Jmeter. Is this possible at all, and if so, what is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RestAssured.proxy](https://javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/5.2.0/io/restassured/RestAssured.html#proxy-java.net.URI-)

If you add the next line to your tests:

```
RestAssured.proxy("localhost",8888);
```

and launch JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy) - JMeter will capture the network traffic and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [HTTP Header Managers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)